# Cant reach HTTPS in tomcat 7 with keystore

Tags: tomcat, https, tomcat7, keytool

I need to setup a https page in my tomcat application.
I don't mind if the whole application is in https or just one page but I can't seem to do it.
I tried it using this tutorial: http://java.dzone.com/articles/setting-ssl-tomcat-5-minutes

Once I did this on my localhost and it worked. But now on my server (which will be used for final publication) it doesn't work. I did change the default tomcat port from :8080 to :80 like this:

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
redirectPort="8443" />
```

The connector for the :8443 port is like this:

```
<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
keystoreFile="/home/pdl14/.keystore" keystorePass="********"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
```

It should work with this setup, but once I try to open the page (https://*.*.*.*:8443) it just gives the error: Page not found of chrome, not even from tomcat.

My server is an Ubuntu 12 server with tomcat 7.
Thanks for helping in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the server that you have hosted your application on is blocking port 8443. Remember that port 8443 is not a standard HTTPs port. The standard one is 443, so you should be able to access it just like https://xyz.com (No port needed).

Also check if traffic over port 443 is allowed.

I suggest the following, change the 8443 in your web.xml to 443. Check your firewall or server settings to allow traffic on port 443. And you should be set. Alternately, if you still want to continue with 8443, then just ensure that your traffic is allowed on port 8443.